# Data transfer between two remote servers linux (sftp)

Tags: linux, shell, sftp, hpc

I work remotely trough my linux system. I have data on server A which can be accessed only through SFTP. The second server is HPC cluster. 
I want to fetch data in my HPN cluster working directory from server A.
How can it be done? Is there any possible batch job script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is doable using SSH - you can either run a script on server A to put the files to the second server or run a script on the second server to pick files from the server A. There's no standard command in SFTP to transfer the files from the server to some other remote location.

Comment: Server A in my case is accessible only via SFTP so SSH would not work in this case.
can you show me what script for for this purpose?
Thanks

Comment: @UmarAsifQureshi SFTP won't let you run scripts. If you don't have SSH access, then your task can't be accomplished with SFTP.